# Issue while generating PDF reports during BirtUpgrade to version 4.4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I an new to Birt Engine. One of my tasks was to upgrade Birt runtime to version 4.4.2 . The PDF reports are being generated without exceptions.

However there is a lot of data mismatch in the PDFs. A lot of the initial values get repeated in subsequent pages. There are no exceptions in the logs.
The PDFs are generating correct data up to Birt Runtime 3.7.0 .

Im not sure whats the root cause of the issue as im new to the technology.I dont see any major change between runtime 3.7.0 and 4.4.2 and so am not sure why this is happening.
Could anyone guide me in anyway?

Adding some part of the code which may be of help.

Part where we initialize birt engine :

```
EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
String birtHome = ReportingProperties.getConstantString("BIRT_HOME");
ReportingServiceLogger.LOGGER.info("Setting BIRT Home: " + birtHome);
config.setEngineHome(birtHome);
config.setLogConfig(null, Level.ALL);
ReportingServiceLogger.LOGGER.info("Starting up platform");
Platform.startup(config);
ReportingServiceLogger.LOGGER.info("Platfor`enter code here`m started");
IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(
IReportEngineFactory.
EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
birtEngine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
birtEngine.changeLogLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

Part where we execute Report Engine :

```
ReportingServiceLogger.LOGGER.info("Executing Report Using BIRT Engine");
design = birtEngine.openReportDesign(inputFilePath);
IRunAndRenderTask task = birtEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
RenderOption options = null;
if (outputFormat.equalsIgnoreCase(ReportingProperties.OUTPUT_FORMAT_XLS)) {
    options = BIRTEngine.renderOptionsXLS();
} else if (outputFormat.equalsIgnoreCase(IRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF)) {
    options = BIRTEngine.renderOptionsPDF();
} else if (outputFormat.equalsIgnoreCase(IRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML) || outputFormat.equalsIgnoreCase(ReportingProperties.OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHART_IMAGE)) {
    options = BIRTEngine.renderOptionsHTML(reportOutputFolder);
}
options.setOutputFileName(outputFilePath);
task.setRenderOption(options);
params.put("outputFormat", outputFormat);
task.setParameterValues(params);
ReportingServiceLogger.LOGGER.info("Run BIRT Task with outputpath : " + outputFilePath);
if (ReportingProperties.getConstantString("EXECUTION_ON_ERROR").equalsIgnoreCase("CANCEL")) {
    task.setErrorHandlingOption(IRunAndRenderTask.CANCEL_ON_ERROR);
} else {
    task.setErrorHandlingOption(
    IRunAndRenderTask.CONTINUE_ON_ERROR);
}
task.run();
task.close();
```

Comment: Please provide your coding sample and  logs.'

Answer (score 0):

Newer BIRT versions cache the results of DataSets. That means, if the report calls the same DataSet with the same parameters again, it will use the cached results from the first call.

Maybe you are using scripted DataSet in the BIRT report or you change values in the DB between DataSet executions or you change the DataSet's SQL dynamically.

This is usually a nice feature, but if the results of the DataSet depend on X somehow, be sure to add X to the DataSet's parameters!